# Spring boot + AWS Linux + Oracle database

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, oracle11g

I have developed Spring Boot REST API with JPA on AWS Linux with `Oracle11g` as database, as we are dealing with Spring boot we don't have to take care of connections.

```
netstat -n | grep 1521
```

When I fired this command to check whether all connections are closed or not, I can see many connections are in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.
Can anyone suggest whether what is wrong in application or configuration of Tomcat or Apache?

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true  
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=30  
spring.datasource.max-active=50  
spring.datasource.max-idle=8  
spring.datasource.min-idle=8  
spring.datasource.initial-size=10  
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000
```

Comment: How on earth does a question like this get upvoted?  *what is wrong in application or configuration of Tomcat or Apache?* - How is that even possible? Are we mind readers?  If you want some code or configuration file examined then at least you need to do is post it

Comment: @ScaryWombat I can't share config file of apache or tomcat either. I just want to know that whether anyone have faced similar issue of having so many CLOSE_WAIT instance open in background.

Answer (score 0):

The issue's been the fact the HttpResponse hasn't been closed, to fix this I've used HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly, see below :

```
HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(createHttpRequest(url, timeOut));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } catch (org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException e) {
        throw new HostUnreachableException(e);
    } finally {
        HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(response);
    }
```

Comment: Do you think we can write this code in Spring Boot application??